# Is there a verb for making a statement/sentence milder or "dumbing it down"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Is there a verb which means the same as "to dumb down" or "to make milder", in relation to an account of something I had witnessed? More specifically, a verb which describes telling your account of something you witnessed in a milder form so as to not scare the other person and "play down" the event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the intent of the eyewitness is to make the event sound less horrifying to the listener, [soft-pedal](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/soft-pedal?s=t), [minimize](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/minimize?s=t), or [sugar-coat](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sugarcoat?s=t) might work.

Comment: +1 Missed your *sugarcoat* reference before posting my deleted one. Suggest you add references (usually links to online dictionaries or other works) which is the preferred approach in this site.

Answer (score 5):

***downplay***

> to treat or speak of (something) so as to reduce emphasis on its importance, value, strength, etc.: *The press has downplayed the president's role in the negotiations.*

Another verb is [***de-emphasize***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/de-emphasize?s=t)

Answer (score 4):

Another option is [*understate*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/understate).

> 1. to state something with less completeness than needed; to minimise or downplay

Answer (score 3):

People often refer to a [***sanitized***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22sanitised%20account%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22sanitized%20account%22&tbm=bks) / [sanitised account](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22sanitised%20account%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) if it omits or [*downplays*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/downplay) *sensational, upsetting,* or *incriminating* (to the speaker) details in the events being recounted.

*Dumbing down* is an informal term for *simplification* - a completely different concept.

Answer (score 2):

What about [soften](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/soften)?

> **Verb**
>
> 1. To make something soft or softer.
> 2. To undermine the morale of someone (often soften up).
> 3. To make less harsh
>
>    - Having second thoughts, I softened my criticism.
> 4. To become soft or softer

Answer (score 0):

To "[simplify](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/simplify)" something means to make it easier to understand.

Comment: It's close, but I'm looking for a verb which describes making a statement milder with the sole intention of not worrying/scaring the other person by making what I saw seem milder or less serious. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @LibEden "Dumbing it down" is not the proper phrase to use in that case.  To "dumb something down" means to make it less difficult to understand, not to reduce the frightening quality of a statement.

Answer (score 0):

In the very specific sense of removing anything that would be considered vulgar or offensive to the audience, especially anything sexual: 'Bowdlerize', after Thomas Bowdler who thought to censor Shakespeare.

Comment: Your answer would get more vote if it provided a quotation, source, a definition etc.

Answer (score -1):

Numb, as in being less felt, less painful.

Comment: You *numb* a story to make it less alarming? [Really?](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/numb)

Comment: I like it.  Never heard it used before, but I have heard of innovation and creative writing.  :-)